# How to write a regular expression to condense folder path name change?

Tags: javascript, regex, path, filenames

I am trying to write a regular expression for JavaScript.

I have file names with folders and I need to consolidate them from the git changes.
e.g.
Input:

```
"9  1   {Folder_Old => Folder}/FileTest1.cs" 
"0  9   File{a => t}est2.cs" 
"-  -   F{a => i}leT{b => e}st.d{c => l}l" 
"9  1   {test/File.cs => test/File1.cs}"
```

Expected Output per line:

```
"9  1   Folder/FileTest1.cs" 
"0  9   Filetest2.cs" 
"-  -   FileTest.dll" 
"9  1   test/File1.cs"
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var myentry = '9 9 {Folder_Old => Folder}/FileTest1.cs'

//find { A => B }

//replace { A => B } with B

let result = myentry.match(/{.+=>.+}/g);
console.log(result[0]) //"{Folder_Old =&gt; Folder}"

result[0] = result[0].replace('{', '')
result[0] = result[0].replace('}', '')
console.log(result[0]) //"Folder_Old =&gt; Folder"

var me = result[0].split(' ')
console.log(me) //["Folder_Old", "=&gt;", "Folder"]

var he = myentry.replace(/{.+=>.+}/g, me[2])
console.log(he) //"9 9 Folder/FileTest1.cs"
```

How can I change my algorithm to cover all the cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you match the replacements (inside `{}`), capturing the new value, you could just replace the match with the captured group.

Match `{.*? => ([^}]+?)}` and replace with `$1`.

Explanation from regex101:

```
{ matches the character { literally (case insensitive)
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
 =>  matches the characters  =>  literally (case insensitive)
1st Capturing Group ([^}])
Match a single character not present in the list below [^}]
+? matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
} matches the character } literally (case insensitive)
} matches the character } literally (case insensitive)
```

```js
var samples = [
      '"9  1   {Folder_Old => Folder}/FileTest1.cs"',
      '"0  9   File{a => t}est2.cs"',
      '"-  -   F{a => i}leT{b => e}st.d{c => l}l"',
      '"9  1   {test/File.cs => test/File1.cs}"'
    ];

samples.forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/{.*? => ([^}]+?)}/gmi, '$1')));
```

[See it at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/wJHJ3d/1/)

Comment: That will work if there is just one match but how about if there are several? e.g. F{a => i}leT{b => e}st.d{c => l}l"

Comment: @aubreyquinn As you see in the regex101 example, it works just fine ;)  Just make sure to set the global flag (`g`)

Comment: Added JS snippet to illustrate :)